# is the $0$ vector of $V$ also in $W$? How do I verify this?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Why is W not a subspace of V here?

[image]

If we let $w(t)=p(t)+q(t)$, then $w(0)=2$ which is not equal to 1. Does this mean that W is not closed under vector addition?

is the $0$ vector of $V$ also in $W$? How do I verify this?

Comment: If p(0) must be 1, how can the zero vector be in W?

Comment: cf. [this closed question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3929559/why-is-w-not-a-subspace-of-v-here)

Comment: What is the zero vector in $\mathbb P_2$?

Comment: I don't understand why p(0)=1 implies that the 0 vector is not in W

Comment: You need the zero **function** to be in $W$ is it is to be a linear space, not just a function that evaluates to zero at a few points. The zero function is zero everywhere, since $p(0) = 1$ for any $p \in W$ it cannot contain the zero function.

Comment: Am I also correct to believe that $W$ is not closed under vector addition?

Answer (score 1):

Not_tiger you know $W$ is not empty. So let $v \in W$. Assume $W$ is a subspace. So $-v$ is also in $W$. $v$ and $-v$ are in $V$. The zero vector is $0=v+(-v)$. The zero vector of $V$ is also zero vector of $W$. But in $W$ there is no zero vector. If there is a zero vector, we must have $a=b=c=0$ but this contradicts with $p(0)=1$.

Comment: do you agree that $W$ is not closed under vector addition?

Comment: yes! p(t)=1 is in W. But p(t)+p(t)=g(t) [g(t)=2] is not included in W.